# Joining tables SQL

Tags: sql

I got 2 tables:

```
SELECT 
    s.case_id, 
    s.start_date,
    s.group_phase_code,
    l.main_phase,
    l.detailed_phase,
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY s.case_id ORDER BY s.start_date) AS row_num
FROM system3020.group_case_phase AS s
LEFT JOIN lookup.case_phase as l
ON s.group_phase_code = l.code
WHERE s.case_id = '1002389';
```

[image]

---

```
SELECT case_id, transaction_date, (-1 * amount) AS amount
FROM system3020.transactions
WHERE case_id = '1002389' AND payment_cost_ind = 'P' AND orig_cost_type != 'IJ'
```

[image]

---

In first table/querie you can see how the phase of the case changed during the time. Start_date show when the the phase started and the start_date of the next phase show then the previous ended.

I need to put the main_phase (from first table/querie) to every transaction date (second table/querie) according to the period in which the transaction happened

For example if transaction happened in 2010-12-16 it should be legal, if happened 2008-09-14 it is amicable

I cannot strict with the case_id or the number of phases as it is filtered, there is a huge data set there each case id can have different number and types of phases

Comment: The sql dialects between mySQL und SQL-Server are different, so be specific about the used RDBMS..

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `PARTITION BY s.case_id` doesn't make sense. You only have one case_id.

Comment: These are not tables, they are queries

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you need is to know the start and end date of different main phases by case.  This query will tell you that:

```
SELECT 
    s.case_id, 
    l.main_phase,
    min(s.start_date) as start,
    max(s.start_date) as end
FROM system3020.group_case_phase AS s
LEFT JOIN lookup.case_phase as l ON s.group_phase_code = l.code
GROUP BY s.case_id, l.main_phase
```

Now that you have that -- you can join when the date is between start and end -- like this:

```
SELECT case_id, transaction_date, s.main_phase, (-1 * amount) AS amount
FROM system3020.transactions
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        s.case_id, 
        l.main_phase,
        min(s.start_date) as start,
        max(s.start_date) as end
    FROM system3020.group_case_phase AS s
    LEFT JOIN lookup.case_phase as l ON s.group_phase_code = l.code
    GROUP BY s.case_id, l.main_phase, 
            l.detailed_phase -- a main phase can have multiple "parts"
) as S ON transactions.case_id = S.case_id
      AND transaction.transaction_date BETWEEN s.start and s.end 
WHERE case_id = '1002389' AND payment_cost_ind = 'P' AND orig_cost_type != 'IJ'
```

Comment: I think it might be the problem then same phases repeat in different time period

Comment: @MikasJankeliūnas I see so then you also need to add in the sub phase to the group by -- I will make the change

Comment: please see my "Answer" to the problem, I have such a phase distribution in mind that legal phase happens in a few different time periods and between them are amicable phases

Comment: @MikasJankeliūnas -- yes this fixes that.  I added the group by of the sub type.  that means the query above will work.